# What does the -> notation after the function parenthesis signify?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, in:

```
  virtual auto create_obj() -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>{};
  }
```

What does -> signify ?
Since the return type is specified as auto, why is it necessary ?

Comment: does this compile?

Comment: @datahaki, of course it does! (given a C++11 compiler)

Comment: Well, sometimes it's nice to give `auto` a helping hand.

Comment: in this case it does nothing really

Comment: @Bathsheba Jokes apart... why is it useful ?

Comment: They are necessary if, say you have a function that's parameterised on two types and the return type is a deduction of those types. See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_trailing_return_types?lang=en

Comment: @Bathsheba I was going to mention that, but even that's not really needed with C++14's `decltype(auto)`

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that it standardizes return type declaration between standard functions and lambda functions

Answer (score 3):

It is referred to as *trailing return type*, it is simply another way to specify the return type of a function.

One situation where it is useful is returning a function pointer from a function. Here is the "standard" syntax:

```
void yoyo(){
    std::cout << "yoyo!\n";
}

void(*my_fn())(){
    return yoyo;
}
```

Versus the more "modern" syntax:

```
auto my_fn() -> void(*)(){
    return yoyo;
}
```

Which is much easier to read.

P.S. The trailing return type can be used for function pointer declarations too:

```
auto yoyo(){ std::cout << "yoyo!\n"; }

auto yoyo_fn() -> void(*)(){ return yoyo; }

auto too_far() -> auto(*)() -> void(*)(){ return yoyo_fn; }
```

Which is pretty contrived, but is much easier to read than if I had to write in the traditional syntax!

Comment: But why use auto then ? May as well have specified the return type the usual way... just seems like unnecessary typing. Surely there must be more to it ?

Comment: @John in your example it is pointless, but I will include an example where it is useful.

Comment: @John It's just a matter of preference. I personally write `auto main() -> int` because it annoys people.

Comment: @PatrickM'Bongo Do you just like typing ? Is this some kind of legacy thing that just didn't go away ?

Comment: @John, no, it's a totally _new_ thing. See the duplicate question/answer.

Comment: @John I added a lil example where it helps readability

Comment: omg. I'm going to have to write a new question to figure out what void(*my_fn())() means... Is that a typo ? How would you even refer to it - There is no function name... unless there is an extra pair of parenthesis around *my_fn... can you explain ?